# There is a log-in error using "cryptoki.dll" using the Pkcs11 library

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#11, hsm, cryptoki

```
    static Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SafeNet\Protect Toolkit 5\Protect Toolkit C SDK\bin\sw\cryptoki.dll");
    public HsmManager()
    {
        try
        {              
            pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
            Slot[] terminals = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(true);
            Slot s;
            Token token = terminals[0].Token;
            Session session = token.openSession(false, false, null, null);
            char[] pass = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
            session.login(true, pass);}}
```

I do the sealing process with the hsm device in c # with the pkcs11 library (without using any other library).
The error message is Message ="CKR_USER_PIN_NOT_INITIALIZED "
What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use real HSM device (PCI/Net provided) or software-only provider? Your code is connecting to software-only Cryptoki provider which might not be what you want...Good luck!

Comment: session.login (iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Session.UserType_Fields.SO, pass)
the problem was solved in this way, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nothing about cryptoki, but I'll try to answer:

Take a look at PKCS#11 standard.

CKR_USER_PIN_NOT_INITIALIZED: 
This value can only be returned by C_Login. 
It indicates that the normal user’s PIN has not yet been initialized with C_InitPIN.

In other words, your token has no PIN.

Try to initialize the PIN or try sending a null PIN in login call (maybe "there is some way for a user to be authenticated to the token without having the application send a PIN through the Cryptoki library")

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to enter the pin field blank, but I get the same error. For the pin start:
session.initp the (pass);
I tried this, but this time it gave the error message "CKR_SESSION_READ_ONLY".
Thank you for the help...

Comment: To initialize the PIN, you need to Login as a Security Officer.


Take a look at PKCS#11 standard, for instance "6.7.1 Read-only session states" and "6.7.2 Read/write session states".

Comment: The Cryptoki token browser seems to have the pins assigned to it, and it can be done without error when it is entered, but when I try to enter it from the code it gives an error. I tried to log in as Code SO (Security Officer). Still, he keeps making mistakes.